# Data set got merged incorrectly/randomly?

Tags: java

I have a `.csv` file that looks something like this:

```
123,1-1-2020,[Apple]
123,1-2-2020,[Apple]
123,1-2-2020,[Beer]
345,1-3-2020,[Bacon]
345,1-4-2020,[Cheese]
345,1-4-2020,[Sausage]
345,1-5-2020,[Bacon]
```

I made a function that finds if both the `number` and `date` of any line is similar, the items of the lines will appended with a number next to it to show how many items are there in the `Set<String>` of items:

```
123,1-1-2020,1,[Apple]
123,1-2-2020,2,[Apple, Beer]
345,1-3-2020,1,[Bacon]
345,1-4-2020,2,[Cheese,Sausage]
345,1-5-2020,1,[Bacon]
```

While this is the intended result, the actual result with a larger set of data using my algorithm, items are sometimes randomly not counted and goes missing (the entire line disappears). The above example sometimes would becomes:

```
123,1-1-2020,1,[Apple]
123,1-2-2020,2,[Apple, Beer]
345,1-3-2020,1,[Bacon]
345,1-4-2020,2,[Cheese,Sausage]
345,1-5-2020,1,[Bacon]
// Any one of those output lines would sometimes disappear entirely.
```

I am very confused why is this happening. Below is the algorithm I implemented:

```
protected List<Receipt> convert(List<Receipt> list) {

        List<Receipt> receipts = new ArrayList<>();
        for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
            List<Receipt> temp = new ArrayList<>();
            temp.add(list.get(i));
            for (int j = i + 1; j < list.size(); j++) {
                if (list.get(i).getNumber().equals(list.get(j).getNumber())) {
                    temp.add(list.get(j));
                }
            }

            Map<String, Set<String>> map = new HashMap<>();
            for (Receipt r : temp) {
                if (!map.containsKey(r.getDate())) {
                    map.put(r.getDate(), r.getItems());
                } else {
                    map.replace(r.getDate(), merge(map.get(r.getDate()), r.getItems()));
                }
            }

            for (Map.Entry<String, Set<String>> m : map.entrySet()) {
                receipts.add(new Receipt(list.get(i).getNumber(), m.getKey(), m.getValue()));
            }
            i = i + temp.size();
        }
        return receipts;
    }

// Merge function used above to append two item sets.
private static Set<String> merge(Set<String> a, Set<String> b) {

        return new HashSet<>() {
            {
                addAll(a);
                addAll(b);
            }
        };
    }
```

Where each line in the `.csv` is made into a `Receipt` object that has `(String)` `getNumber()`, `(String)` `getDate()`, and `(Set<String>)` `getItems()` method.

For a .csv with a similar format that has hundreds of thousands of lines, in the original data set, for example, the item `Bacon` was found 1334 times but the output of my algorithm, `Bacon` only appears randomly somewhere between 1160 - 1240 times. This happens to all other items as well. There are also some strange behaviors where a few random lines got the items appended wrong as well (same number, different date but still appended).

What could possibly be the cause of this randomness?

Edit : as suggestions in the comment section mentioned, the cause seems to be at `i++` and `i = i + temp.size()` incrementing the `i` value incorrectly.

Comment: Shouldn't there be only one `1-4-2020` line, like this? `345,1-4-2020,3,[Cheese,Sausage,Bacon]`

Comment: @Andreas thanks for pointing out. It's a typo, I already fixed the example.

Comment: Shouldn't the `1-4-2020` line have a count of 2?

Comment: @Andreas yes, that as well. I've been working for too many hours and my brain hardly functions any more. Thanks for pointing out again.

Comment: can you share your `Receipt` class?

Comment: also the definition of your data. e.g. what is the first number at the beginning of each line?

Comment: Are all of the lines with a given `number` guaranteed to be contiguous? If not, `i = i + temp.size()` will skip the wrong lines sometimes.

Comment: @Mr.Brickowski The first number is just something like customer ID. This is the link to download the whole project if you would want to take a look: https://mega.nz/file/zrwCzSqC#vzCRk3tY4gZBImBqwPUmk76_j23HrbbpJpaP1PF63X0

Comment: @tgdavies I'm also a little bit suspicious on that one as well but it's so difficult for me to track even in debug mode because of the large data set. I have the download link of the project here if you care to take a look: https://mega.nz/file/zrwCzSqC#vzCRk3tY4gZBImBqwPUmk76_j23HrbbpJpaP1PF63X0

Comment: In the line `temp.add(list.get(j));`, if j != i + temp.size() I think you have a problem. (I'm probably off-by-one, but I think that's useful to check.) You could run your input through `sort -t , -k 1`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you're using double-brace syntax in the `merge()` method, which is highly discouraged. See e.g. this answer: [What is Double Brace initialization in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27521360/5221149)

Second, your code is iterating the list too much, you can (and should) do it in a single iteration.

Before going on, we need to look at the `Receipt` class, which is not shown in the question, but we can infer that it looks like this:

```java
public class Receipt {
    private final String number;
    private final String date;
    private final Set<String> items;
    public Receipt(String number, String date, Set<String> items) {
        this.number = number;
        this.date = date;
        this.items = items;
    }
    public String getNumber() {
        return this.number;
    }
    public String getDate() {
        return this.date;
    }
    public Set<String> getItems() {
        return this.items;
    }
}
```

The goal is to merge receipts that share `number` and `date`. To do that in a single iteration, we need a `Map`, keyed by the combination of `number` and `date`. There are 3 ways to do that:

1. Implement `equals()` and `hashCode()` to be based on only those two fields, ignoring the `items` field. This is the easiest and simplest solution, but requires modifying the `Receipt` class, and to define "equality" to not include the item list, which is a debatable decision, so let us not do this.
2. Implement a dedicated class with just the two fields, and implement `equals()` and `hashCode()`. This has the advantage of leaving `Receipt` alone, but does require a new class.
3. Use the `Receipt` class as the key, but give the `Map` class a custom `Comparator` that only compares the two fields. With Java 8, we can do this without creating a new class, so let us try that. We'll need to use a `TreeMap` in order to supply a custom `Comparator`.

So, we'll create a `TreeMap<Receipt, Set<String>>`, using a custom `Comparator`, iterate the list once, merging the items as we go, then finally iterating the map to build the new list of merged receipts.

```java
protected static List<Receipt> convert(List<Receipt> list) {
    Map<Receipt, Set<String>> map = new TreeMap<>(Comparator.comparing(Receipt::getDate)
                                                        .thenComparing(Receipt::getNumber));
    for (Receipt receipt : list) {
        map.merge(receipt, receipt.getItems(), (v1, v2) -> {
            Set<String> newSet = new TreeSet<>(v1);
            newSet.addAll(v2);
            return newSet;
        });
    }
    List<Receipt> result = new ArrayList<>();
    for (Entry<Receipt, Set<String>> entry : map.entrySet()) {
        result.add(new Receipt(entry.getKey().getNumber(),
                               entry.getKey().getDate(),
                               entry.getValue()));
    }
    return result;
}
```

It can of course also be done with Stream logic:

```java
protected static List<Receipt> convert(List<Receipt> list) {
    return list.stream()
        .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(
                Function.identity(),
                () -> new TreeMap<>(Comparator.comparing(Receipt::getDate)
                                              .thenComparing(Receipt::getNumber)),
                Collectors.flatMapping(r -> r.getItems().stream(),
                        Collectors.toCollection(TreeSet::new))))
        .entrySet().stream()
        .map(e -> new Receipt(e.getKey().getNumber(), e.getKey().getDate(), e.getValue()))
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```

*Test*
<sub>Uses Java 9 `of` methods.</sub>

```java
List<Receipt> list = List.of(
        new Receipt("123", "1-1-2020", Set.of("Apple")),
        new Receipt("123", "1-2-2020", Set.of("Apple")),
        new Receipt("123", "1-2-2020", Set.of("Beer")),
        new Receipt("345", "1-3-2020", Set.of("Bacon")),
        new Receipt("345", "1-4-2020", Set.of("Cheese")),
        new Receipt("345", "1-4-2020", Set.of("Sausage")),
        new Receipt("345", "1-5-2020", Set.of("Bacon")));

List<Receipt> converted = convert(list);
converted.forEach(r -> System.out.println(r.getNumber() + "," + r.getDate() + "," +
                                          r.getItems().size() + "," + r.getItems()));
```

*Output*

```
123,1-1-2020,1,[Apple]
123,1-2-2020,2,[Apple, Beer]
345,1-3-2020,1,[Bacon]
345,1-4-2020,2,[Cheese, Sausage]
345,1-5-2020,1,[Bacon]
```

Comment: Aboslutely beautiful solutions (even two of it!) and really opened my eyes. However, there's two thing I'd like to ask:

1/ If there are two `receipt` items with exact same number, date and item purchased (an edge case that actually happened), how should I handle this using your method?

2/ I'm really interested in knowing more about method 1 and 2 you mentioned as well, do you mind to enlighten me a bit more about it?

Comment: @Mint Since your `items` is a `Set`, a duplicate item is ignored. --- As for `equals()` and `hashCode()`, you implement them in the standard way, except ignoring the `items` field. Whether as part of `Receipt` or as part of separate `ReceiptKey` class that doesn't even have an `items` field, they are the same. Then use `HashMap` instead of the `TreeMap` used here.